# How to get id of anchor tag on its click and pass it on to a servlet page?

Tags: javascript, java

```
    stu Id: <input type="text" id="stuid" /> stu Name: <input type="text" id="stuname" />

    <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/heafitblog" id="link1" onclick="myFunction()">link</a>



</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var eleid = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].id;
        alert(eleid);
    }
</script>
```

I have tried this.I am able to get the id but I don't know how to pass the value of eleid variable to called path i.e ../heafitblog and get the id there.I want to do it without hidden input as my anchor tag are not inside the form.

Comment: You can pass it using parameters `/heafitblog?id=link1` but passing it back to server doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: I have 6-7 links and according to the link which is clicked I am performing different different actions.That,'s why I want to pass the id.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way to pass the element to the function after clicking and then get the ID of the element by calling **getAttribute** method

Please have a look on your **onclick** method mentioned on anchor tag as well as on **script** tag

Please refer the code below:

```
stu Id: <input type="text" id="stuid" /> stu Name: <input type="text" id="stuname" />

<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/heafitblog" id="link1" onclick="myFunction(this)">link</a></body>

<script>
    function myFunction(element) {
        var eleid = element.getAttribute('id');
        alert(eleid);
    }
</script>
```